# SQL add string as a parameter

Tags: c#

```
//cmd.CommandText = @"select MaKH from KHACHHANG where HoTenKH='a'";
cmd.CommandText = @"select MaKH from KHACHHANG where HoTenKH=$tenKH";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("$tenKH", tenKH));
```

The comment line works, cmd is a DbCommand, I've tried

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select MaKH from KHACHHANG where HoTenKH='$tenKH'";
```

But it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or are you getting zero results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems silly, but are you making sure to do this:

```
string tenKH = "a";
```

before doing this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select MaKH from KHACHHANG where HoTenKH = @tenKH";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@tenKH", tenKH));
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly reasonable question. And he still hasn't told use what "doesn't work".

Comment: This really makes sense. I pass tenKH = textBox.ToString();  , I change to tenKH = textBox.Text; < Pure string, and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Sorry for wrong vote, you get my best vote, with respect :) I'm a young developer.

Answer (score 1):

Use an @ sign instead of $ to prefix your parameter name

Answer (score 1):

SQLite uses a colon to designate a named parameter, not a dollar sign. Try

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select MaKH from KHACHHANG where HoTenKH=:tenKH";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("tenKH", tenKH));
```

You could also use the @ symbol if you want the code to look more like SQL Server code:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select MaKH from KHACHHANG where HoTenKH=@tenKH";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("tenKH", tenKH));
```

Comment: @nXqd: Did you try a colon instead? See my first example.

Comment: I've tried both ways, HoTenKH in MaKH Table is char(30) , tenKH is a string. Does it cause problem ?

Comment: I don't know SQLite, but with other databases, the prefix character for the parameter name needs to be used in both the SQL statement and the parameter definition, e.g., new SQLiteParameter(":tenKH", tenKH); // note added colon, or @ sign, whichever you use.

Comment: @Cylon: It's worth a try. I'm not a SQLite developer, but the examples I saw online omitted the prefix. Note that `SqlParameter`s do not require the prefix.